How To Deploy an Angular and Node.js app on IIS
I have  Angular 17  project  with .Net core as backend
I added node.js as backend in angular project
working perfectly on my localhost but on production not working i got "Method Not Allowed"

Server.js
const express = require("express");
const multer = require("multer");
const path = require("path");
const cors = require("cors");

const app = express();
const PORT = 4000;

app.use(cors());

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function(req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, "../src/assets/Folder/");
    },
    filename: function(req, file, cb) {
        cb(
            null,
            file.fieldname + "-" + Date.now() + path.extname(file.originalname)
        );
    },
});
const fileFilter = (req, file, cb) => {
    // Check if file is an image or video
    if (
        file.mimetype.startsWith("image/") ||
        file.mimetype.startsWith("video/")
    ) {
        cb(null, true);
    } else {
        cb(new Error("Only image and video files are allowed"));
    }
};

const upload = multer({
    storage: storage,
    fileFilter: fileFilter,
    limits: { fileSize: 2000000 },
});

app.post("/upload", upload.single("file"), (req, res) => {
    if (!req.file) {
        return res.status(400).json({ message: "No file uploaded" });
    }
    res.status(200).json({
        message: "File uploaded successfully",
        filename: req.file.filename,
    });
});

app.use("uploads", express.static("uploads"));

// Error handling middleware
app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
    if (err instanceof multer.MulterError) {
        // Multer error occurred (e.g., file size exceeded)
        return res.status(400).json({ message: err.message });
    } else if (err) {
        // Other errors (e.g., unsupported file type)
        return res.status(400).json({ message: err.message });
    }
    next();
});

app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running on http://localhost:${PORT}`);
});

proxy.config.json
{
    "/api/**": {
        "target": "http://demo.example.com",
        "secure": false,
        "changeOrigin": true,
        "pathRewrite": {
            "^/api": ""
        }
    }
}

Web.Config
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>

<system.webServer>
  <rewrite>
    <rules>
 <rule name="Angular Routes" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url=".*" />
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
      <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^.*/admmmin" negate="true" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
      </rule>

           <rule name="redirect1" stopProcessing="true">
                        <match url="^(.*)Admin" />
                 
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
                        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="(.*)/admin/(.*)" />
                    </conditions>
                    
                </rule>
    </rules>
  </rewrite>
</system.webServer>

</configuration>

So how can fix it ?
Can Publish it to the dist folder then upload it as angular ?

it would probably help to include iis config

@traynor i updated the question so you can check the web config

well, I'm not familiar with .net, but ng and node code look fine to me

Method Not Allowed is usually a 405 error, you can use failed request tracking to view detailed error information, this will generate detail log file, which will help you to identify the problem.

@samwu thank you, but still give me same message "405 - HTTP verb used to access this page is not allowed.The page you are looking for cannot be displayed because an invalid method (HTTP verb) was used to attempt access."

This error message is only what you see in the browser. What I mean is that you need to use failed request tracking to see the specific cause of the error.

Angular 17 produces its build in a browser subfolder, and there's no way around this, except perhaps of adding a command which moves the files one level up. However, this web.config should be able to reroute all requests to index.html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>

<system.webServer>
  <rewrite>
    <rules>
      <rule name="Browser subfolder" stopProcessing="false">
        <match url="(.*)" />
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" pattern="^browser/" negate="true" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Rewrite" url="/browser/{R:1}" />
      </rule>
      
      <rule name="Angular Routes" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url=".*" />
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Rewrite" url="./browser/index.html" />
      </rule>
    </rules>
  </rewrite>
</system.webServer>

</configuration>

